# php - trouble sending multiple POST requests

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

I have a total of four forms which the user can send. The first is a `"field-form"` which contains a variety of field resources which the user can select. The second is an `"admin-form"`, contains administrative resources. The third is a `"tech form"` and the fourth a `"student-form"`.

Once the user has made his selection and submits a request to verify the quote, the request is as follows:

```
<form name="field-form" class="form-class" method="POST" action="quote.php">
  <ul id="field-list">
    <li id="field-element-0" class="li-element-field">
      <input type="number" id="resorce-amount" name="r_num[]"> 
      <label id="chosen-lbl"> Secratary</label>
      <input type="number" id="resource-duration" name="r_duration[]">
      <label id="country-lbl"> from </label>
      <select id="ctr-lbl" name="r_country[]">
         <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Because there are four types of resource classes containing different resources (hence four forms) there are four possible POST requests. They all would look like the one above but with a different name attribute.

I have a button which I added a click event listener to and it triggers the following function to submit the different forms to be handled by the php:

```
function submitQuote(e) {
var collection = document.getElementsByClassName("form-class");

for(let i = 0; i<collection.length;i++) {
    collection[i].submit();
}
```

}

The issue is that when the user has selected more that one resource type (thus sending more than one POST request), I only receive the last POST request on the php side.

This is what is on the php:

```
$r_num = $_POST["r_num"];
$r_dur = $_POST["r_duration"];
$r_ctr = $_POST["r_country"];

for($i = 0;$i < 6 ;$i++) {
    echo "num:" . $r_num[$i];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "dur:" . $r_dur[$i];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "ctr:" . $r_ctr[$i];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "-----------$i----------<br>";
}
```

I've tried using the GET request but I think the issue might be how I'm sending the requests. Could someone please help me see what I'm missing

Comment: one form = one request, technically. so you only "see" the last one, because all requests before that get cancelled / results omitted. what you actually want (should want, that is) is ONE single request containing all the forms' data. Now, I don't know how you select your forms to be send, (and it looks like there is no logic at all and you just submit all of them) just replace your multi-form with a single form.

Comment: @Jakumi Thank you. I didnt realise that is what was happening. You've given me a more efficient approach.